# C++ cpp files as modules

Tags: c++, modularity

Sorry if I am duplicating other question but I don't know how to google it.
I want to add some minor modularity to my program: some .cpp files should be compiled as "modules". The main requirement is that I should be able to add modules by just adding new .cpp file to the project, without changing other files in any way.

Achieving this looks easy with dynamic loading libraries. Main program can scan some folder for all .dll files, load each of them and call exported "load" symbol from every module. In destructor main program can call "unload" symbols so modules can clean up.

I want the same but with monolithic program. Is there any way for .cpp files to register themselves so main program can call their init() functions at some point? Or for main program to find all such modules?

How it is done in Linux kernel? I know simple adding .c files makes them work somehow.

Comment: You can statically link everything?

Comment: From my tracking there is no way for a .cpp file to add itself to main, all .cpp files need some form of header file attached to it...  you could look at:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm  for an example...

Comment: _"all .cpp files need some form of header file attached to it"_ The main program can expose a registration interface.

Comment: _"How it is done in Linux kernel? I know simple adding .c files makes them work somehow."_ The kernel module needs to be compiled as a module to add it. These kernel modules need to provide a certain interface, to make that working.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ _"The kernel needs to be recompiled if a new kernel module is added"_ Does it? What about `modprobe`?

Comment: Are you talking *dynamic* libraries or *static* libraries?

Comment: @Lightness I probably worded that bad. Not the kernel needs to be compiled but the new modules.

Comment: The operating system has functionality for finding dynamic libraries.  The dynamic libraries have a "table of contents" listing the functionality.  Your program may have to tell the OS where to look for the dynamic library.

Comment: I understand how to do it with dynamic loading libraries. But now I am making monolithic program. There are plenty of options in linux kernel config. Enabling some of them simple adds some .c files to compilation (drivers for example). And they work somehow...

Comment: Just wait for C++17 modules (modules do not exist in standard but exist in standard specifications sheet. So it means clang++ will probably have modules implemented

Answer (score 2):

You can use a static dummy variable inside every cpp file and initialize it by a lambda doing the initialization and registration. Trivial example:

```
// registration.h

void register_cpp (std::string name);
void print_cpps ();

// registration.cpp
namespace {
   std::vector<std::string> & names () {
      static std::vector<std::string> names_ {};
      return names_;
   }
}

void register_cpp (std::string name) {
   names ().push_back (name); // well, push_back(std::move (name)) would be more efficient
}

void print_cpps () {
    for (auto && name : names()) { std::cout << name << "\n"; }
}

// a.cpp

#include "registration.h"
static std::nullptr_t e = ([] () { register_cpp ("a"); return nullptr; }) ();

// b.cpp

#include "registration.h"
static std::nullptr_t e = ([] () { register_cpp ("b"); return nullptr; }) ();

// main.cpp
#include "registration.h"
int main () {
   print_cpps ();
   return 0;
}
```

I think you need `names_` to be a static local variable in order to make sure that it is initialized before being accessed for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can add new `.cpp` files to a statically linked application without changing the existing code using a registration interface that is exposed from the main application (singleton).

Something like

App.h:

```
 struct IModule {
     virtual void init() = 0;
     virtual ~IModule() {}
 };

 class App {
 public:
      void registerModule(IModule* newModule); // Stores the interface
                                               // pointer of an additional
                                               // module
      static App& instance() {
           static App theInstance;
           return theInstance;
      }
 };
```

NewModule.cpp:

```
 #include "App.h"

 class NewModule : public IModule {
 public:
      void init();
 private:
      NewModule() {
          App::getInstance().registerModule(this);
      }

      static NewModule instance;
 };

 NewModule NewModule::instance;
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to test this! I understand NewModule.cpp but not totally sure I understand App class... Is it singleton of some kind? How it initialized..? Need some time... Thanks again!

Comment: @Sion0 Yes it's a _Singleton_ as I mentioned. It's initialized at `static App theInstance;`

Comment: I dont know if things have changed with C++11, but I have used this paradigm long ago and AFAIK the linker ignored the `NewModule::instance` seeing it was not utilized explicitly anywhere, so we had to add some code such as `forceLink` that just references these static instances, in order to force the linker construct them so they register themselves.

Comment: @A.S.H May be that's necessary, IDK. But what I know that for instance google test test classes work in a similar way and I didn't need to specify such linker option.

Comment: Seems like it works like expected, thanks. I also tried to figure out how module registration implemented in Linux kernel but I am not cool enough for such things. [link](https://www.quora.com/Init-Call-Mechanism-in-the-Linux-Kernel-When-the-module-in-loaded-in-the-kernel-then-module-init-function-gets-called-How-this-call-happen-internally)  - something about symbol exporting...